# Is it the best way to create MMORPG game using an Unreal Engine with a custom server in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm creating an open world multiplayer game in Unreal Engine 4 with a custom server written in C++ (using asio/flatbuffers libs). I have configured packet transfer between the game and the server. Chat messages and player movement are working now, but I ran into the problem of simulating player actions on the server.

My next steps (for now):

1. simulate player collisions with terrain and static meshes on the server
2. simulate projectile physics (like fireballs, bow arrows, etc)

For the first step, I need to have on the server the code for handling the collision of the player with the terrain, the data for this terrain, and the bounding box of the player. But the problem is that this code is already in the engine, and I would not like to manually transfer this code, terrain data and bounding box of player that I created in Unreal Editor. With the second step, this is the physics code and the same bounding box, but for the projectile.

My ideas for a solution: somehow take all the necessary engine code and use it on the server (I have a console application called BlankProgram that has engine libraries connected to it). But even if it works, there is still a problem with transferring the data of the actors that I create in the editor (player bounding boxes, projectile speed, direction, etc.). In this case, perhaps a self-written plugin can help me, which uploads the necessary data to the server files.

Is my approach and ideas correct or is there a better way? There is a dedicated server from the Unreal Engine, but somehow there is little information about it and people say that it is not suitable for MMORPG. I also know that some companies write their own servers (not from the Unreal) for games under the Unreal Engine. I would like advice on where I should dig to simplify the work. I want to write compatible code between the game and the server, without doing unnecessary code copying and other things.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow isn't good place for such open-ended questions. I wish I could point to a decent forum for more open-ended questions but I just don't know of any.

Comment: @Elliott, I will also try to ask on the unreal engine forums. Thanks =)

Comment: There's [GameDev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but even there you'll likely be voted down for it being open-ended.

Comment: Admittedly I don’t have experience with mmo net code specifically. But still, I feel like you’re overthinking this. 

In fighting unreal you’re generating a lot of work for yourself. Clearly unreal’s net code works fine if used well with at least 64 players. 

I would treat it as any other unreal game, so you can still draw on the knowledge there is about creating them. 

Unreal’s built in net code debugger is amazing, and there’s also a built in profiler so you can analyse exactly how much data you’re sending and how that affects gameplay.

Comment: If you were to get a huge uptake of users you could then consider running many dedicated servers. Other mmos call these worlds, and sometimes they’ll even have separate servers for “instances” of say 12 players. Which goes along with some kind of backend (server that supports many players but doesn’t do anything contributing to gameplay), that could be used to record player/world state and drive your chat system. At that point there might also be scope for re writing bits of the engine to better suit your game’s needs.